# For the events A, B, C ⊂ Ω

Tags: probability

I am new to probability and I have been trying to find a formula or an intution to solve the following problem.

For the events A, B, C ⊂ Ω the following probabilities are known:
$P(A) = 0.05$, $P(B) = 0.1$, $P(A∩B) = 0.03$, $P(A∪C) = 0.42$, $P(A∩C) = 0.03$, $P(C \setminus(A∪B)) = 0.34$,
$P(A∩B∩C) = 0.02$. Calculate the probabilities:

1. $ P((A \cap C) \setminus B) $
2. $P(A^c ∩ B ∩ C^c)$

My solution to $1.$ is to calculate probability as follows:
$P((A ∩ C) \setminus B) = P(A∩C) - P(A∩B∩C)$ and for the $2.$ I don't know how to solve this.

How could one solve this?

Comment: Have you considered drawing yourself a venn diagram?

Comment: As for (1), that is correct.  For (2) it may well be easier to look at the opposite probability, $\Pr(A\cup B^c\cup C)$ and try to do something with that, perhaps by expanding with inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @JMoravitz yes I have considered drawing the venn diagrams. For (2), I shaded the region of b (not including (a ∩ b) ,(b ∩ c) and (a∩ b∩ c)) and all other regions except for a and c. Is that representation correct?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: To find $P((A\cup C)\cap B)$ (which you need to subtract from $P(B)$), apply $P(U\cup V)=P(U)+P(V)-P(U\cap V)$ to $U=A\cap B,V=C\cap B$.

Comment: When I suggested drawing the venn diagram, it was not merely to look at a graphical representation of the set in question, but rather to use it as an organizational tool to help you fill in the corresponding values.  Typically you do so from inside to out.  You are told $\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)=0.02$ so that number goes in there.  Then you are told $\Pr(A\cap B)=0.03$ so when taken with the $0.02$ from the middle implies you need to write an additional $0.01$ in the region corresponding to $\Pr(A\cap B\cap C^c)$.  Similarly you can fill out the rest in rather quick succession.

Comment: While this can indeed be overkill for certain problems, it is also mindless and requires very little thought.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what *JMoravitz* suggested in the comments, here's the Venn diagram. The variables denote the probabilities for the respective regions.

[image]

The question tells us -

$$\begin{align*}
a+b+c+d &= 0.05 \\[0.3cm]
b+c+e+f &= 0.1 \\[0.3cm]
b+c &= 0.3 \\[0.3cm]
a+b+c+d+e+g &= 0.42 \\[0.3cm]
c+d &= 0.03 \\[0.3cm]
g &= 0.34 \\[0.3cm]
c &= 0.02 \\[0.3cm]
\end{align*}$$

For part $(2)$, you need to find $f$. Should be easy from here.